# SQL: Order by column, then by substring mix asc and desc

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Example: In my warehouse I have rows and each row has 5 shelves.

I'm walking through the aisle and have row 1 to my right and row 2 to my left, I start picking an order from row 1 going up from 1 to 5 then I go to row 2 down from 5 to 1.

I have a column in database as follows:

```
01-001-A-01
01-002-A-02
01-003-A-03
01-004-A-01
01-005-A-03
02-001-A-01
02-002-A-02
02-003-A-03
02-004-A-01
02-005-A-03
```

The first 2 letters are the rows and the next 3 letters are the shelves, I would like to achieve that the second row should be in DESC order while the first (and third etc) should be in ASC order. As follows:

```
01-001-A-01  
01-002-A-02  
01-003-A-03  
01-004-A-01  
01-005-A-03  
02-005-A-03  
02-004-A-01  
02-003-A-03  
02-002-A-02  
02-001-A-01
```

So basically each odd row will be ASC and each even will be DESC.

Comment: what about rest of the rows other than second and first ?

Comment: Same thing, basically each odd row will be ASC and each even will be DESC. Thanks

Comment: First normalise your schema. That means a column for rows, a column for shelves, and a column for whatever's left. MOD() will solve the rest of the problem. And figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: I'm using SAP which stores it all in 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519673)</kbd>

```
select *
from #temp
order
by substring(id,1,2),
case
when substring(id,1,2)%2=0 then row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) desc)
else row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) asc)
end
```

Comment: Great answer! Now how would I handle if I have results that jumps a row (after 01 I have 03 so no items to pick from row 2 ) so after 01-005-A-03  I want 03-005-A-03 meaning that in this case I would like row 3 DESC and row 4 ASC?

Comment: can you please ask this a new question ,i cant understand by your comments

Comment: I recomend asking a new question along with expected output based on the data

Comment: added here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682383/sql-case-then-remember-and-evaluate-based-on-last-group-result thanks

Comment: Lets continue discussion in chat please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121560/room-for-harry-and-thegameiswar