# SQL Case Then: remember and evaluate based on last group result

Tags: sql-server

Example: I have the following case then statement (see here [SQL: Order by column, then by substring mix asc and desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681490/sql-order-by-column-then-by-substring-mix-asc-and-desc) ) my warehouse and the locations are in 1 column as follows and the case alternates the rows going from ASC (odd) to DESC (even):

```
select *
from #temp
order
by substring(id,1,2),
case
when substring(id,1,2)%2=0 then row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) desc)
else row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) asc)
end

01-001-A-01
01-002-A-02
01-003-A-03
01-004-A-01
01-005-A-03
02-001-A-01
02-002-A-02
02-003-A-03
02-004-A-01
02-005-A-03
03-001-A-01
03-002-A-02
03-003-A-03
03-004-A-01
03-005-A-03
```

Now I would like to add the following: I pick an order from row 1 but nothing to pick from row 2 so I want to go to row 3, now I don't want to walk back the aisle to the beginning of row 03-01 because I'm close to 03-05, so I would like that my results should always be alternating between ASC and desc, so after 01-005-A-03 if I have 0 results with 02 then I want 03-005-A-03 meaning that in this case I would like row 3 DESC and row 4 ASC (so always do the opposite than in the previous group?

This is how it should be if no result begins in 02-XXX-X-XX

```
    01-001-A-01
    01-002-A-02
    01-003-A-03
    01-004-A-01
    01-005-A-03
    03-005-A-01
    03-004-A-02
    03-003-A-03
    03-002-A-01
    03-001-A-03
```

Comment: Mysql or SQL-server?

Comment: SQL server. updated

Comment: when i was about to paste answer i saw one message stating new answer,after pasting my answer,i could see both my answer is  same as posted answer..so deleted mine now..You could see demo here if you wish..https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `ORDER BY` clause to

```
order by 
    substring(id,1,2),
    case
    when dense_rank() over (order by substring(id,1,2)) % 2 = 0 
    then row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) desc)
    else row_number() over (partition by substring(id,1,2) order by  SUBSTRING(id,4,3) asc)
    end
```

instead of finding modulo of `substring(id,1,2) % 2` , use `dense_rank()` to get the continuous numbering and then find the modulo of it

Note : the original query would failed if your first segment is not pure numeric